# lighbox codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Instanciei tudo direito os arquivos do lighbox, mas por alguma razão ele abre uma nova abra mostrando a img, ao invés de mostrar a box do lightbox.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Galeria de imagens</title>
    <!--Le CSS
    ==========================================================-->        
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>includes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript">                
   <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>includes/lightbox/dist/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript" />

    <!--Le JavaScript
    ==========================================================-->        
   <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>includes/lightbox/dist/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>        
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>includes/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>       
</head>     
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <?= $menu ?>        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
                <a href="/painel/galeria_add/<?= $this->uri->segment(3) ?>"><button class="btn btn-success">Inserir Fotos</button></a><br /><br />
                <a href="/painel/index"><button class="btn btn-info">Voltar</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <?
        $x=1;        
        ?>        
        <div class="row">    
            <?
            foreach($fotos as $foto){
            ?>

            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <div class="panel panel-<?= $foto['thumb_path'] == $fotoDestaque[0]['image_path'] ? 'primary' : 'default' ?>">
                    <div class="panel-heading"> <strong>Foto 0<?= $x ?> <?= $foto['thumb_path'] == $fotoDestaque[0]['image_path'] ? 'DESTAQUE' : '' ?></strong>  </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <a href="<?= base_url() ?><?= $foto['thumb_path'] ?>" src="<?= base_url() ?><?= $foto['thumb_path'] ?>" rel="lightbox" data-lightbox="example-set">
                           <div class="bg-center-center" style="background-image:url(<?= base_url() ?><?= $foto['thumb_path'] ?>);  width:100%; height:250px; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>                                        
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <a class='btn btn-danger' href="/images/delete/<?= $this->uri->segment(3) ?>/<?= $foto['id'] ?>" onclick="return confirm('Deseja realmente excluir essa foto?')">Excluir</a>
                        <a class='btn btn-info' href="/painel/setDestaque/<?= $this->uri->segment(3) ?>/<?= $foto['id'] ?>" onclick="return confirm('Deseja colocar essa foto de Destaque?')">Destaque</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?$x++;}?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: aperte F12 e verifique no console se está retornando alguma mensagem de erro

Answer (score 0):

Olá, eu creio que o seu problema é o fato de que você está chamando o Jquery depois de chamar o Lightbox. Coloque o script do jquery antes que irá funcionar, como abaixo:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>     
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>includes/lightbox/dist/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>        
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>includes/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

E também lembre-se de colocar o endereço da mesma imagem ou de uma versão maior dela no link.

Answer (score 0):

Este problema ocorre por vários motivos, muitas vezes porque o css não está chamando corretamente ou porque o javascript não está pegando. 
Verifique também se está chamando a função .lightbox(). 
OLhe no console e verifique se está com erro de javascript, assim ficará mais fácil para você verificar o problema. 
Tenta baixar novamente os arquivos e verifica se os links que você está puxando estão funcionando. 
Se por um acaso não der certo, mude o script do lightbox de lugar, e deixe após o jquery.

Coloque o jquery no topo, antes de qualquer script.

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```